# How can I bind a keybord shortcut on my Thoinkpad X220 Tablet?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.04, lenovo, thinkpad, tablet

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad X220T (or X220 Tablet).

I have set up two scripts to enhance the screen rotation, and I would like to bind them to a keyboard shortcut.

Basically, I added these lines on `/etc/rc.local`:

```
setkeycodes 67 202 # Launch3
setkeycodes 6c 149 # Launch2
```

to bind the second and the third buttons on the edge of the screen to the "Lauch2" and "Launch3" buttons.

[image: buttons]

Then I try to add a custom shortcut to my scripts, but nothing happends.

Please note that if I link the scripts to a keyboard shortcut, like `ctrl+alt+B`, they work.

The scripts are the following:

```
  #!/bin/sh

# Find the line in "xrandr -q --verbose" output that contains current screen orientation and "strip" out current orientation.

rotation=`xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) (normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)'`
# Using current screen orientation proceed to rotate screen and input tools.

echo $rotation
case "$rotation" in
    normal)
 #    -rotate to inverted
    xrandr -o inverted
    xsetwacom set "10" Rotate half
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate half
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate half
    ;;
    right)
 #    -rotate to inverted
    xrandr -o inverted
    xsetwacom set "10" Rotate half
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate half
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate half
    ;;
    inverted)
 #    -rotate to normal
    xrandr -o normal
    xsetwacom set "10" Rotate none
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate none
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate none
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

# Find the line in "xrandr -q --verbose" output that contains current screen orientation and "strip" out current orientation.

rotation=`xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) (normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)'`
# Using current screen orientation proceed to rotate screen and input tools.

echo $rotation
case "$rotation" in
    normal)
 #    -rotate to the right
    xrandr -o right
    xsetwacom set "10"  Rotate ccw
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate ccw
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate ccw
    ;;
    inverted)
 #    -rotate to the right
    xrandr -o right
    xsetwacom set "10"  Rotate ccw
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate ccw
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate ccw
    ;;
    right)
 #    -rotate to normal
    xrandr -o normal
    xsetwacom set "10" Rotate none
    xsetwacom set "11" Rotate none
    xsetwacom set "15" Rotate none
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you resolve it? I am still running happily on that machine and just set it up with new Linux Mint LTE. But I cannot make it work again. I can't find my old resources either. Help would  be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I have spend some time on this problem in 2023. I am running Linux Mint (Ubuntu based) on a Lenovo X220T

1. By installing the Thinkpad Scripts from Mark Ueding
   https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts
   You can at first get keycodes for the buttons. Don't miss the reboot!
2. Place the rotate script some where:
   https://github.com/Erik-J-D/rotatescripts
3. Installing `xbindkeys` to run the rotate script.
   For example with the second bezel button from left:

```
"~/projects/rotateScreen/rotate.sh"
    m:0x0 + c:162
    XF86TaskPane
```

That's it.